# Running celery tasks using custom ConsumerStep

Tags: celery

I have been trying to find a way to consume and process messages from a Rabbitmq broker that are produced by another service and **don't** follow the celery [message protocol](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/internals/protocol.html#message-protocol).

From what I've seen the custom consumer step can be done as explained in [documentation](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/extending.html#custom-message-consumers)

This is Ok for my case but I cant find a way to forward the decoded consumed message to a worker.

Processing the message in `hande_message` function would actually be done in the MainProcess and not on any worker process.

Calling `my_task.delay()` inside `handle_message` function, is the only workaround i can think of but, re-sends the message to the broker which I really don't want to do.

What am I missing? How can I start a task after I have consumed the message?